# How can I split this regex up to make more readable?

Tags: javascript, regex

and still keep it in the object literal:

```
url:       /:\/{0,3}(www\.)?([0-9.\-A-Za-z]{1,253})([\x00-\x7F]{1,2000})$/,
```

In addition how can I simplify it.

It is just a mess in the current state. I'm not worried about accuracy right now.

Here is my try from Crockford's book:

```
makeRegex: function () {
    var parse_url = /^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\/{0,3})
                    ([0-9.\-A-Za-z]+)
                    (?::(\d+))
                    ?(?:\/([^?#]*))
                    ?(?:\?([^#]*))
                    ?(?:#(.*))?$/; 
},
```

Comment: Are the capture groups useful? Do you need to capture something?

Comment: I do ... I need the domain ... only the domain ... it is a mess right now ... I should probably delete and start over.

Comment: What language are u using ? Most languages have small libs to handle this properly ;)

Comment: JavaScript ... wow that give an unterminated regular expression ...

Comment: If you want features like free-spacing and comments, you can use the module XRegExp: http://xregexp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are notoriously unreadable. They don’t like extra spaces and they don’t have comments. Your only possible solution is to construct a string and then turn that into a regular expression.

Here are the steps I went trough

Target Regular Expression

```
var regex=/:\/{0,3}(www\.)?([0-9.\-A-Za-z]{1,253})([\x00-\x7F]{1,2000})$/;
```

Use `RegExp` to construct the expression from a string.

```
var parse_url = RegExp(':/{0,3}(www\\.)?([0-9.\\-A-Za-z]{1,253})([\\x00-\\x7F]{1,2000})$');
```

Remember:

- the `/` delimiters at the beginning and the end of the expression are not there — they’re only in a RegEx literal
- the `\` characters in the string are doubled, because the string has its own interpretation of them

Break the string up by adding `'+'` as strategic points:

```
var parse_url = RegExp(':/{0,3}(www\\.)?'+'([0-9.\\-A-Za-z]{1,253})'+'([\\x00-\\x7F]{1,2000})$');

var parse_url = RegExp(':/{0,3}(www\\.)?'+
    '([0-9.\\-A-Za-z]{1,253})'+
    '([\\x00-\\x7F]{1,2000})$');
```

It’s not a very good solution, but that’s all you can do with a regular expression.

Modern JavaScript does support multi-line strings in the form of the template literals, but that probably won’t help much here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest breaking a regular expression into parts and assigning each part to a well-named variable, with a comment if necessary. An example, which is meant to demonstrate the principle rather than correctly validate URLs, since a URL-matching regex is hard to write (https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex):

```
var protocol = '(?:https?|ftp)'; // Protocol can be "http", "https" or "ftp"
var domain = '([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)'; // Alphanumeric characters separated by periods
var path = '(?:[A-Za-z0-9\.\/]+)'; // Alphanumeric characters, . or /
var regexp = Regexp(protocol + '://' + domain + '/' + path);
```

Now you have the regular expression broken into smaller, more easily understood mini-expressions, and the overall expression is a lot easier to read.